# python read file from url and write binary data file, get messy code

Tags: file, python-2.7, encoding, urllib2

python: 2.7

I want to download css files from url and store to local disk. But encoding is a problem, so I want to bypass it by writing binary bytes to file, like this:

```
 req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
 css = req.read()
 with open("file.css", 'wb') as w:
     w.write(css)
```

I can open the url with browser to get the content of the file, but the file stored is something like this: ‹������Í=ËŽãÈ‘÷ú¸öHŸ¥Â¼;žÛú²†...

Where do I go wrong? And how can I just store the file as it is, I get stuck but I don't think it should be very difficult.

Can you help me out please?

Comment: what sort of file are you trying to get ?  What do you expect to see if it's binary content ?

Comment: This happens because the file isn't downloaded correctly, file gets corrupted probably due to network issues. The file is actually text file, so I should be able to read the content. So I solved the problem by detecting its encoding, if the confidence is very high then I believe the file is intact. This is a solution, but if there is any better solution, please tell me. Thanks for your reply. :)